# What does エセインテリ mean?

Tags: meaning, loanwords, prefixes

is it like a pseudo-intellectual or something else?

Comment: You have answered your own question.

Answer (score 9):

Yes.

エセ = 似非 = pseudo; fake; quack; etc. (似非関西弁、似非医者、似非学問, etc.)

インテリ = intellectual